# How to make that hair, coat & similar things animate automatically?

Tags: animation

How to make that hair, coat & similar things animate automatically?

Example:
[image]

Comment: cloth simulation

Comment: And how animate polygonal hair?

Comment: cloth simulation as well. :)  I don't use this often but if you would like to post a .blend I can try a few settings and get back to you with any progress I've made.

Comment: Yes, please: http://zalivalka.ru/226909. Here is hair & coat.

Comment: I tried the model you posted but for some reason it causes my computer to freeze once I add the Cloth simulation.  Sorry about that.  :)

Comment: Also, I think all those bones for the cloth and hair will probably interfere with the cloth simulation so you may have to remove them.  Or you can do the animation the hard way by animating all the bones instead of using Cloth.  I guess it depends what you are doing with this.  Is it being exported again afterwards?

Comment: Animate manually it's very long and the result is bad and unlikely. That is why I want that hair and clothes animate automatically. I tried animate using Cloth but hair looks like castoffs: http://s017.radikal.ru/i411/1506/ae/72727efc4bd0.gif.

Comment: Maybe you look and edited to have the correct settings? Here: http://zalivalka.ru/227017.

Comment: silly :) You've already done better than I know how to do.  What you've done looks really good, nice work :)

Comment: I don't quite like this result but thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic setup for using a cloth simulation.  It's really basic and uses all default settings.

For the 'clothes' or 'mesh-hair' you would add a ***Cloth*** Modifier which you can add through the Physics tab.  I've indicated the button in the attached image below.

For objects that will affect the cloth shape, you can add a Collision Modifier which is also located in the ***Physics*** tab.  Just make sure that you have the proper object selected when you add each of the Modifiers(that isn't clear from the images ;)

[image]

Now make sure the ***Timeline*** is set to the first frame and start the animation.  You can use the ***Play*** button in the Timeline or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to run the simulation.

Here is what this looks like when you run it.

[image]

Stop the animation when it looks the way you would like it to. If you want to 'freeze' the Cloth sim, you can press the ***Apply*** button for the Cloth Modifier under the Modifiers tab.